# For loop value displaying on the Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matlab-figure

I have a for loop with `c=1.00016161:0.00000001:1.0001617`. In each iteration I draw a figure and I want the `c` value in each iteration to be displayed on the title. I don't mind if it gets displayed on the x or y axis. I just want that particular `c` value to be displayed somewhere on the plot.

But Matlab round off these values so that all the values I get in the figures are the same.

For example, if I use the code `title(num2str(c(k)))` MATLAB round it off and display as 1.0002. I included `format long` but it doesn't solve the issue.

How can I get the full value displayed on the plot without having it rounded off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
title(sprintf('%.8f',c(k)));  %8 digits to the right of the decimal point
```

Take a look at [*'Format of output fields'*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#input_argument_d0e935708) in the documentation of [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to see what 'number' of plot it is, and only the last 5 digits are important. Therefore I would suggest the following:

```
title(num2str(c(end-5:end)));
```